# CNN model keeps returning same output

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

This is the code for classifying medicinal plants. I got a 94.5% accuracy. But still the model shows same output regardless of any change in input.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import PIL.Image
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
data_dir = "/content/drive/MyDrive/imgClassifer/plant_samples(unzipped)/"
img_height, img_width = 512 , 512
batch_size = 32
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  shuffle=False,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
print(train_ds.class_names)
print(val_ds.class_names)
class_names = train_ds.class_names
print(class_names)
for image_batch, labels_batch in train_ds:
  print(image_batch.shape)
  print(labels_batch.shape)
  break
normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.2),
])



normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
normalized_ds = normalized_ds.map(lambda x, y: (data_augmentation(x), y))
image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))
first_image = image_batch[0]

# Notice the pixel values are now in `[0,1]`.
print(np.min(first_image), np.max(first_image))
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
num_classes = 21

IMG_SHAPE = (512,512,3)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet',
                                               )


base_model.trainable = False



preProcess = tf.keras.Sequential([
  normalization_layer,
  data_augmentation
])
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=IMG_SHAPE)

global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
x = preProcess(inputs)
x = base_model(x)
x = global_average_layer(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
outputs = prediction_layer(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.compile(
  optimizer='adam',
  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
  metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=10
)
scores = model.evaluate(train_ds, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
model.save_weights("/content/drive/MyDrive/imgClassifer/savedModelTrainable/savedBaseModeNonTrainable.ckpt")
model.save("/content/drive/MyDrive/imgClassifer/savedModelTrainable/savedModel.ckpt")
def decoder(index):
  global class_names
  return class_names[index]
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model = load_model("/content/drive/MyDrive/imgClassifer/savedModelTrainable/savedModel.ckpt")

#testing the model
import os
import cv2
import imghdr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img=cv2.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/imgClassifer/plant_samples(unzipped)/alfalfaa/alfalfaa_10.jpeg")





plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

import imghdr

image_format = imghdr.what("/content/drive/MyDrive/imgClassifer/plant_samples(unzipped)/alfalfaa/alfalfaa_10.jpeg", h = None)
print(image_format)
if image_format is None:
    print("Invalid image format.")

img = cv2.resize(img,(512,512))
img = np.reshape(img,(1,512,512,3))
img_normalized = cv2.normalize(img, None, 0, 1.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
img_normalized/=255
classes = ['abscess', 'acai', 'alfalfaa', 'aloe', 'amargo', 'ashok', 'ashwagandha', 'Avaramsenna', 'bilberry', 'bittermelon', 'Bitterorange', 'borage', 'cannabis', 'Cayenne', 'chamomile', 'Eurphorbia', 'GA', 'Goldenseal', 'henna', 'thristle','Arnica']
model_output_multi_class = model.predict(img_normalized)
print(model_output_multi_class)
multi_class_prediction = classes[np.argmin(model_output_multi_class[0])]
print(multi_class_prediction)
```

Tried changing inputs as well as no. of epochs. Dont know what seems to be the problem. New to tensorflow. Any and all suggestions are welcome regardiing the program as there can be many mistakes. So please help me with this.